# Проверка в списке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список в python, к примеру:

```
active_disputes = [[2148800000, 192943472, 1],[21488234000, 192941472, 1],[2148899900, 178943472, 2]]
```

При выполнении условия должна идти проверка, нет ли в списке `active_disputes` подсписка начинающегося с определенного числа. Если нет - требуется добавить в `active_disputes` такой подсписок, если есть, то написать, что такой подсписок уже есть. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если конечно я правильно понял условие, то так:

```
active_disputes = [[2148800000, 192943472, 1],[21488234000, 192941472, 1],[2148899900, 178943472, 2]]

l = False
n = [2148800000, 192943472, 1]
for i in active_disputes:
    if i[0] == n[0]:
        l = True
        break

if l:
    print('Подсписок уже есть')
else:
    active_disputes.append(n)

print(active_disputes)
```

Comment: 1) А почему бы после `l = True` не вызывать `break`? Нет ведь смысла все перебирать, если флаг все-равно не поменяется. 2) `if l == True` излишне, просто `if l:`

Comment: Ответ поправил, действительно так код выглядит лучше

Comment: Завтра проверю Вашу реализацию, хотя уже так вижу, что должно работать. Могу привести мой код, который работал несовсем корректно, но возможно он даст вам более полное представление.

Comment: @DORONUN, это нужно делать сразу, а не могу, не могу, для полноценного ответа и разбирательств, нужно приводить минимально рабочий пример или ошибки с примером в котором они возникают и что конкретно у вас не получается.